# Trying to inherit three base classes and can't

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a few questions related to the design of my `User` class but
they are different enough that I think they should be independent
questions.

So, the first is related to inheritance of base classes. I am currently
inheriting two classes, `ProfileBase` and `ISessionMgrEntry` as such:

```
public class User : ProfileBase, ISessionMgrEntry
```

But, I also want to inherit a third class, `MembershipUser`, like this:

```
public class User : ProfileBase, MembershipUser, ISessionMgrEntry
```

However, the compiler won't let me do that. Why? And, how do I get
around this?

Thanks.

PS - ASP.NET 3.5 / C#

**EDIT**

Hi. I think the below solution may work for what I am trying to acheive. It seems pretty simple and straight forward. I am doing this so I can create a complete/combined `User` object. Does anybody see any reason why this might cause problems? One that came up while I was ding this is overlapping properties. For example, both `MembershipUser` and `ProfileBase` share "`UserName`". Should I just chose one or the other or will this be a design flaw? Suggestions? Thanks again.

```cs
public class User
{
    #region Constructors
    
    private readonly MembershipUser _MembershipUser;
    private readonly ProfileBase _ProfileBase;
    
    #endregion

    public User()
    {
        _MembershipUser = new MembershipUser();
        _ProfileBase = new ProfileBase();
    }

    public string Comment
    {
        get { return _MembershipUser.Comment as string; }
        set { _MembershipUser.Comment = value; }
    }

    public bool IsAnonymous
    {
        get { return _ProfileBase.IsAnonymous as bool; }
    } 

    ....
}
```

Comment: Why as you doing `as` on the props?

Comment: You are right, I thought that looked off. I was following this convention but realize that its a different case: 

[SettingsAllowAnonymous(false), CustomProviderData("IPAddress;string")]
        public string IPAddress { get { return base["IPAddress"] as string; } set { base["IPAddress"] = value; } }

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the first example you're not actually inheriting from two classes, but from one class and an interface.

C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance from classes, but does allow you to implement multiple interfaces. See <del>[this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/85562.aspx)</del> (link is dead so text is pasted below) for more information on why.

You will have to make an `IMembershipUser` interface and implement that in your `User` class.

Interfaces are usually given names based on the concrete class name prefixed by an `I`. So the class `MembershipUser` would have an interface `IMembershipUser`. There's nothing stopping you using some other name, but everyone who uses interfaces is used to this naming convention.

> There are a number of reasons we don’t implement Multiple
>   Implementation Inheritance directly. (As you know, we support Multiple
>   Interface Inheritance).
>
> However, I should point out that it’s possible for compilers to create
>   MI for their types inside the CLR. There are a few rough edges if you
>   go down this path: the result is unverifiable, there is no interop
>   with other languages via the CLS, and in V1 and V1.1 you may run into
>   deadlocks with the OS loader lock. (We’re fixing that last problem,
>   but the first two problems remain). The technique is to generate some
>   VTables in RVA-based static fields. In order to deposit the addresses
>   of managed methods (which probably haven’t been JITted yet), you use
>   the VTFixup construct. This construct is a table of triplets. The
>   triplets consist of a token to a managed method, an address in your
>   image that should be fixed up (in this case, a slot of the VTable you
>   are creating in the RVA-based static), and some flags. The possible
>   flags are described in corhdr.h and they allow you to specify 32- vs.
>   64-bit pointer sizes, control over virtual behavior, and whether some
>   reverse-PInvoke behavior should be applied in the form of a thunk that
>   eventually dispatches to the managed method. If we are performing an
>   unmanaged->managed transition, you also have some control over which
>   AppDomain should be selected for us to dispatch the call. However, one
>   of these options (COR_VTABLE_FROM_UNMANAGED_RETAIN_APPDOMAIN) doesn’t
>   exist in V1. We added it in V1.1.
>
> There are several reasons we haven’t provided a baked-in, verifiable,
>   CLS-compliant version of multiple implementation inheritance:
>
> 1. Different languages actually have different expectations for how MI works. For example, how conflicts are resolved and whether duplicate
>      bases are merged or redundant. Before we can implement MI in the CLR,
>      we have to do a survey of all the languages, figure out the common
>      concepts, and decide how to express them in a language-neutral manner.
>      We would also have to decide whether MI belongs in the CLS and what
>      this would mean for languages that don’t want this concept (presumably
>      VB.NET, for example). Of course, that’s the business we are in as a
>      common language runtime, but we haven’t got around to doing it for MI
>      yet.
> 2. The number of places where MI is truly appropriate is actually quite small. In many cases, multiple interface inheritance can get the
>      job done instead. In other cases, you may be able to use encapsulation
>      and delegation. If we were to add a slightly different construct, like
>      mixins, would that actually be more powerful?
> 3. Multiple implementation inheritance injects a lot of complexity into the implementation. This complexity impacts casting, layout,
>      dispatch, field access, serialization, identity comparisons,
>      verifiability, reflection, generics, and probably lots of other
>      places.
>
> It’s not at all clear that this feature would pay for itself. It’s
>   something we are often asked about. It’s something we haven’t done due
>   diligence on. But my gut tells me that, after we’ve done a deep
>   examination, we’ll still decide to leave the feature unimplemented.

Comment: Thanks Chris. 
Could you take a look at my Edit when you have a moment? thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Code Sherpa - I'd really need to see more of your code and have more of a conversation than is possible via SO, but if you have got duplicated properties you ought to be looking at a different class hierarchy.

Answer (score 12):

in c# you just can **inherit from one class**, but **implement as many interfaces** as you want.
in your case `ProfileBase` and `MembershipUser` are classes and `ISessionMgrEntry` is an interface.

Answer (score 9):

C# only supports single inheritance. You can either chain together your classes (i.e. `MembershipUser` inherits from `ProfileBase`) or use `interfaces`.

Answer (score 4):

C# does not allow [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.

In the first example you are inheriting from `ProfileBase` and declaring your class to be implementing the `ISessionMgrEntry` interface.

You can add as many interfaces to a class as you want (provided you implement them all).

Answer (score 3):

C# only allows single inheritance: you can only inherit from one base class. In the first case `ISessionMgrEntry` is an interface which is different from a base class.  Here's a good article on the difference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973861.aspx

In the second case you are trying to inherit from both `ProfileBase` and `MembershipUser`, which the compiler won't allow.  The best way to get around this would be to encapsulate one (or both) of `ProfileBase` and `MembershipUser`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple interfaces with identical member names are not a problem.  If the members can share the same implementation, just create a public member with the same name; if they can't share the same implementation, you can just explicitly implement one (or all) of the members.

For example, `IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable`, and both provide a `GetEnumerator()` method with differing return types.  Consequently, `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is generally explicitly implemented:

```
class Foo : IEnumerable<object>{
    // explicitly implement IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator ()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator ()
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Calling `GetEnumerator()` in `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` isn't an infinitely recursive call; it calls the public member of the same name, *not* itself (i.e. the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` method).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance can be achieved with interfaces.
Example Derived has to inherit from Base1, Base2 and Base3.

```
class Base1 { public abstract void Method1(); } //base class 1
class Base2 { public abstract void Method2(); } //base class 2
class Base3 { public abstract void Method3(); } //base class 3

//helper interfaces
interface IBase1 { Base1 { get; } } 
interface IBase2 { Base2 { get; } }
interface IBase3 { Base3 { get; } } 

class Derived: IBase1, IBase2, IBase3 { //derived class

  public class D1 : Base1 {  //custom implementation of Base1 class
    public override void Method1() { /* derived Method1 code */ }
  } 
  public class D2 : Base2 {  //custom implementation of Base2 class
    public override void Method2() { /* derived Method2 code */ }
  } 
  public class D3 : Base3 {  //custom implementation of Base3 class
    public override void Method3() { /* derived Method3 code */ }
  } 

  //classes as members
  D1 d1;
  D2 d2;
  D3 d3;
  //....

  //interface implementation
  public Base1 => d1;
  public Base2 => d2;
  public Base3 => d3; 
}
```